# How to execute a function on page load with ng-init() without being affect by other elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I've been away from coding for about 4 years, and now I'm re-learning programming with PHP 7 and AngularJs. I build a simple CRUD application to study some concepts, and I have a simple table that display the records on my db, so far I've managed to sort the table and it works fine. The problem is, I populate the table by calling a function with ng-init, it loads the function just fine, but the problem is, when I type on the TextBoxes above the table to insert a new Record, it keeps sorting out the table below. And I've already google it but could not find an answer to my problem. Hope someone can help me.

```
   <body >
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <h1>BANCO PHP - CADASTRO DE CLIENTES</h1>
        <hr>

    </div>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="cntrl" ng-init="showclientes()"> 
    <div class="row container">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id">Id</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Id" id="id" ng-model="id" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nome">Nome</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" ng-model="nome">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="saldo">Saldo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Saldo" id="saldo" ng-model="saldo">
            </div>

            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" value="{{nomebotao}}" ng-click="insertdata()">

            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><label class="bg-success">{{msg}}</label>
        </div>
            </div> <!-- div row form -->


        <div class="row container">
            <hr>
            <h3>RESULTADOS</h3>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

            <th><a href="#" ng-click="tipoOrdem = 'id*1'">Id<span ng-show="tipoOrdem == 'id'; ordemReversa = !ordemReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            </a></th>


            <th><a href="#" ng-click="tipoOrdem = 'nome'">Nome<span ng-show="tipoOrdem == 'nome'; ordemReversa = !ordemReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            </a></th>


            <th><a href="#" ng-click="tipoOrdem = 'saldo'">Saldo<span ng-show="tipoOrdem == 'saldo'; ordemReversa = !ordemReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            </a></th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cliente in data | orderBy:tipoOrdem:ordemReversa">

            <td>{{cliente.id}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente.saldo}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="deletecliente(cliente.id)" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></button>
            <td><button ng-click="updatecliente(cliente.id, cliente.nome, cliente.saldo)" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-edit fa-lg"></button>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div> <!-- div row table --> 


    </div> <!-- div controler -->

</div> <!-- div main container -->


<!--  javascript funcoes -->

<script>
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('cntrl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.tipoOrdem = 'id*1';
    $scope.ordemReversa = false;
    $scope.nomebotao="Salvar";



    $scope.insertdata=function(){

        $http.post("insert.php", {'id':$scope.id, 'nome':$scope.nome, 'saldo':$scope.saldo, 'botao':$scope.nomebotao})
        .success(function(){

            $scope.msg= "Data Saved";
            $scope.showclientes();
        });
    }

    $scope.showclientes=function(){
        $http.get("select.php")
        .success(function(data){

            $scope.data=data

        });

    }


    $scope.deletecliente=function(id){
        $http.post("delete.php", {'id':id})
        .success(function(){
            $scope.msg="Registro excluído.";
            $scope.showclientes();
        });
    }

    $scope.updatecliente=function(id,nome,saldo){

        $scope.id=id;
        $scope.nome=nome;
        $scope.saldo=saldo;
        $scope.nomebotao="Atualizar";

    }



});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: May I ask why you use `id*1` do instead of just `id` ?

Comment: When I use just the id the sorting works wrong, it would sort something like this: 1 12 13 2 3 4 . I don't know why!

Comment: Hmm I've just tried it with the sort links as below.. It doesn't seem to now .Try this http://jsfiddle.net/maxcache/b2L02ggr/2/ ? It is possible that due to the incorrect binding it was just doing it all over.. If your id is passed as string that might also cause the issue you mention. but as an int/number it should work..

Answer (score 0):

I can only find an issue with this `sort` links which is putting itself in infinite loop causing [$rootScope:infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) .. Update them like so..

```
<th><a href="#" ng-click="tipoOrdem = 'id';ordemReversa = !ordemReversa">Id<span ng-show="tipoOrdem == 'id' && ordemReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
</a></th>


<th><a href="#" ng-click="tipoOrdem = 'nome';ordemReversa = !ordemReversa">Nome<span ng-show="tipoOrdem == 'nome' && ordemReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>

</a></th>


<th><a href="#" ng-click="tipoOrdem = 'saldo';ordemReversa = !ordemReversa">Saldo<span ng-show="tipoOrdem == 'nome' && ordemReversa" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
</a></th>
```